# ios h264 Bitstream with sliced IDR

Tags: ios, avfoundation, h.264, bitstream

I have an iOS app, which needs to display a h264-video stream. The stream is in bitstream format and working well when the IDR is one single H264-Frame/Unit. Now I have a video-source, which splits the IDR in 4 sepearte H264-Frames/Unit (each display 1/4th of the picture). This can not be handled by my current approach NALU->AVCC, since each of the IDR will overwrite the previous one.

To clear confusions about what I recieve:

This is the working Situation: |SPS|PPS|IDR|B_FRAME|.....|SPS|PPS|IDR|

This is what is what I recieve: |SPS|PPS|IDR|IDR|IDR|IDR|B_FRAME|.....|SPS|PPS|IDR|IDR|IDR|IDR|

I tried to combine these IDR into one frame. I tried to convert all into AVCC format and pass them as one unit to the AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer